# Angular 2 multiselect OnInit

Tags: typescript, angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I have an issue I hope you guys can help me out, it seems like the jQuery code is not loaded with the `OnInit` implementation.

Here's an image to show whats going on: http://i66.tinypic.com/2f0b090.jpg

As you can see it is not loading the jQuery code below and tried to set an timeout around it:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.dropdown-list').multiselect();

        $('#select-form').on('reset', () => {
            console.log('check');

            $('#dropdown-list option:selected').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('selected', false);
            });

            $('#dropdown-list').multiselect('refresh');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

It is only loaded after I push an other object Expression in my case. Like the second pic: http://i66.tinypic.com/3486ejp.jpg it adds an new line of expression builders

Comment: too many jquery code in one angular app. I'm sure you don't need jquery at all. Read docs about ViewChild @ https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html .. the example is reference to component, by you can reference any native element as @ViewChild("angular_element_id") elementRef:ElementRef and later use it as this.elementRef.nativeElement.<ANY_HTMLElement_METHOD>(...)

Comment: BTW, I think you need to use NgZone wrapper in your code in question, in order to make it work. see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html